# 415 (Unsupported Media Type) with jquery

Tags: java, jquery, json, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to using a RESTful API and I don't know why it is showing this error.
I am posting the values through jQuery. Do I need to do something else? This is my jQuery code:

Updated : Now it is showing  **405 (Method Not Allowed)**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 


$("#patsubmit").click(function() {
    var firstName = $("#firstName").val();
    var lastName = $("#lastName").val();
    var mobileNumber = $("#mobileNumber").val();
    var emailId = $("#emailId").val();

   var dataString = '{"firstName":"'+ firstName + '","lastName":"' + lastName + '","mobileNumber":"' + mobileNumber + '", "emailId":"' + emailId+'"}';
   console.log(dataString); 
   if(firstName=='' )
    {
alert("nothing in it");
    }
    else
    {
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
     url : '/geniedoc/api/patient/register',
     data: dataString,
     contentType: 'application/json',
     dataType: 'json',
     headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
    success: function(){ // Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
console.log();
   }
});}
    return false;
    });

});
```

This is my Java API. `MAIN_PATIENT` = `api/patient` and `RestURIConstants.REGISTER` = `register`

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = RestURIConstants.MAIN_PATIENT)
public class PatientRestController extends AbstractController implements RestURIConstants, GenieDocConstants{

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserRestController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = RestURIConstants.REGISTER, method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes ="application/json")
    public @ResponseBody ModelMap registerPatient(HttpServletRequest  request, @RequestBody PatientVo patientVo){
        logger.info("registerPatient : Start");
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        ModelMap map = new ModelMap();
        PatientVo patVo;
        try {
            if(patientVo.getFirstName() == null) {
                map.addAttribute(STATUS_CODE, FAILURE);
                map.addAttribute(STATUS_MESSAGE, this.env.getProperty(MESSAGE_FIRST_NOT_EMPTY));
            } else if(patientVo.getEmailId() == null) {
                map.addAttribute(STATUS_CODE, FAILURE);
                map.addAttribute(STATUS_MESSAGE, this.env.getProperty(MESSAGE_EMAIL_NOT_EMPTY));
            } else if(patientVo.getEmailId() == "") {
                map.addAttribute(STATUS_CODE, FAILURE);
                map.addAttribute(STATUS_MESSAGE, this.env.getProperty(MESSAGE_EMAIL_NOT_EMPTY));
            } else if (patientVo.getMobileNumber() == null) {
                map.addAttribute(STATUS_CODE, FAILURE);
                map.addAttribute(STATUS_MESSAGE, this.env.getProperty(MESSAGE_MOBILE_NOT_EMPTY));
            } else {
                patVo = this.patientManagementService.provisionPatient(patientVo);
                if (patVo != null) {
                    map.addAttribute("patientId", patVo.getEmailId());
                    map.addAttribute(STATUS_CODE, SUCCESS_STATUS_CODE_REGPATIENT);
                    map.addAttribute(STATUS_MESSAGE, this.env.getProperty(SUCCESS_STATUS_CODE_REGPATIENT));

                } else {
                    map.addAttribute(STATUS_CODE, ERROR_STATUS_CODE_REG);
                    map.addAttribute(STATUS_MESSAGE, this.env.getProperty(ERROR_STATUS_CODE_REG));
                }
            }
        } catch (MongoDBDocumentNotFoundException e) {
            map.addAttribute(STATUS_CODE, ERROR_STATUS_CODE_REGPATIENT);
            map.addAttribute(STATUS_MESSAGE,this.env.getProperty(ERROR_STATUS_CODE_REGPATIENT));
            logger.error("Error : " + e.getMessage());
            //e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UserAreadyExsistException e) {
            map.addAttribute(STATUS_CODE, ERROR_STATUS_CODE_REGPATIENT);
            map.addAttribute(STATUS_MESSAGE, this.env.getProperty(ERROR_STATUS_CODE_REGPATIENT));
            logger.error("Error : " + e.getMessage());
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
        logger.debug("Exit: Total Time Taken: "+ (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
        return map;
    }
```

Comment: Why did you remove the url from your AJAX request? You also don't need to call `JSON.stringify`, you already have a string.

Comment: ok edited now it is showing // Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier on success part of jquery @zeroflagL

Comment: Remove the `headers: ...` line. A comma is missing, but you already set the content type with `contentType: ...` anyway.

Comment: You could set org.springframework.web log level to debug, and check the spring request mapping log when startup web container. I think maybe u visit the wrong url, (/geniedoc part?)

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the **Content-Type Header** to **application/json**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/geniedoc/api/patient/register',
    data: dataString,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type':'application/json'
    }
   .....
}
```

In your spring controller you are defining, that only content of MIME Type **application/json** is accepted. Because standard content type text/plain the Spring controller does not accept your request and send back a status code 415 (Media type not supported)

**Edit:** As user6409738 mentioned, you need to send your data in json format. Otherwise the Spring Controller will cause an exception parsing the body.

For example the solution posted by Yagnesh Agola

```
var dataString = '{"firstName":"'+ firstName + '","lastName":"' + lastName + '","mobileNumber":"' + mobileNumber + '","emailId":' + emailId+'"}';
```

It depends what your PatientVo Class is looking like

Comment: i beleive data also shoud be under json? right? if i m right then why syntax i should use to get the data under json

Comment: Of course. When the controller accepts the request, it would then complain that it cannot parse the body, because it is not in json format

Comment: i have used your way now it is showing error 400 bad request

Comment: Status Code 400 means that the data you've send is invalid. That means you are not sending a valid json content. You need to change your dataString

Comment: ok edited now it is showing // Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier on success part of jquery @Lorenz

Answer (score 0):

Data you have send to server from client is not in JSON format.

```
var dataString = 'firstName='+ firstName + '&lastName=' + lastName + '&mobileNumber=' + mobileNumber + '&emailId=' + emailId;
```

Above line is used to send data string to server which is not in JSON format it is simple query string.

Either you can convert above string in JSON format

```
var dataString = '{"firstName":"'+ firstName + '","lastName":"' + lastName + '","mobileNumber":"' + mobileNumber + '","emailId":"' + emailId+'"}';
```

OR

You can directly submit form data in JSON using below code.

```
var formData = JSON.stringify($("#myForm").serializeArray());
```

Comment: You don't have to send JSON, `form-urlencoded` data is fine too

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes you are right but i am correcting what user is write.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i have used Lorenz way with header but it is showing 400 bad request now

Comment: i have used your way too it is showing  405 (Method Not Allowed)

Comment: output {"firstName":"sda","lastName":"asd","mobileNumber":"fcs@d.com","emailId":asda"}

Comment: @user6409738 please check updated one. i miss last double quote for emailid value.

Comment: @YagneshAgola already did it but it is showing 400 bad request

Comment: ok edited now it is showing // Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier on success part of jquery

Comment: @user6409738 You miss semi colon at the end of line above `success:fun..` line. Please update your code and than try this. you can find this error easily in browser consol

Answer (score -1):

1. add contentType parameter when use jQuery Ajax

> ```
> $.ajax({
>   type : "POST",
>   contentType : 'application/json',
>   url : "/geniedoc/api/patient/register",
>   data : JSON.stringify({"param1" : "param1", "param2":2})
> })
> ```

2. remove consumer = "application/json" in your request-mapping definition, (it's not necessary, SpringMVC will auto detect right converter)

because U use *@RequestBody* in springMVC controller, then SpringMVC will convert the argument with *RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor* which use default converters to resolve the argument. default converters list is:

```
public RequestMappingHandlerAdapter() {
        StringHttpMessageConverter stringHttpMessageConverter = new StringHttpMessageConverter();
        stringHttpMessageConverter.setWriteAcceptCharset(false);  // see SPR-7316

        this.messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>(4);
        this.messageConverters.add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
        this.messageConverters.add(stringHttpMessageConverter);
        this.messageConverters.add(new SourceHttpMessageConverter<Source>());
        this.messageConverters.add(new AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter());
    }
```

For your situation, *MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter* is expect to be used to resolve the argument. And here is the definition of MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter, it need MediaType of application/json

```
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    super(objectMapper, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8,
            new MediaType("application", "*+json", DEFAULT_CHARSET));
}
```

Comment: The reason is not correct. The ResponseBody annotation does not say that json is used. You could also use xml. The content Type is defined in the RequestMapping annotation

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I didnt see the consumer definetion. But it's the same, even u remove the consumer define, if u didn't specify  the correct content type, the default converter will still not able to convert the message.